# How to fix problem with tabstop configuration in ~/. vimrc

Tags: vim

I set tab configuration in ~/.vimrc as below:

set ts=4 sts=4 sw=4

I notice that if the word is 4 characters long or above, the cursor shift into right 4 spaces as in configuration for tabstop.

But if the word is less than 4 characters long, it didn't shift into 4 spaces.

Example:

```
'name' + <Tab>: tab produced correct number of spaces (i.e 4 spaces)

'age'  + <Tab>: tab produced wrong number of spaces (i.e 1 space only)
```

Why is it ?

Does the word length effect tab?

What can I do if I want to shift the cursor to 4 spaces as configured regardless of the word length?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that the `tabstop`, `shiftwidth`, and `softtabstop` options work is that they control indentation to certain points that are commonly referred to as "tab stops".  In other words, they're designed to always indent to a column that's a multiple of the setting.

So if your tab stops are at multiples of 4, then hitting the Tab key will cause the cursor to indent to a column that is the next multiple of 4.  This is the behavior of inserting a literal tab (U+0009, CHARACTER TABULATION) into a document and then rendering it on a normal terminal (except that the width is usually 8 there).  This results in text that is aligned at fixed columns, which is the desired style for most programming languages and text markup formats.

As you've noted, this does result in different amounts of indent if the words are different lengths.  Typically in code, we would just cause the second column to be at the next tab stop and not care that the indents are of different lengths.  That is, in your example, we'd hit Tab once on the first line and twice on the second, and start the next column at column 8.

I'm not aware of any way to force Vim to insert a specific number of spaces other than the standard editing commands.  Normally users who are in this situation just hit Space four times if they really want four spaces and not an indentation to the next tab stop.  You can of course create a mapping if you need to do that a lot.

Comment: Are there any other kinds of tab ? Where is a tab counted from? Is it from the beginning of line or from the current cursor position?

Comment: You can either insert spaces or a tab depending on the setting of the `et` variable.  The columns are counted from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably inserting regular tabs, which display variable-width according to what’s before and after. I find having `set list` on is really handy for this (though you probably will want to change the `listchars` setting).

If you really want spaces (which I find better anyway), use `set expandtab`.

Also, most long-time users recommend leaving `tabstop` at 8, since you can’t control how wide every one’s tabs are.

Comment: Hello, I tried as you said but it didn't work at all. What setting is really used for tab.Is it ts, sts or sw? I've just set ts to 8 but when i press tab, it only produces 4 spaces instead of 8. I read some documents about tabs setting but i don't understand what is the differences among ts,sts and sw. Please share with me what you understand about them, when should i congifure tabstop or softabstop or shiftwidth.

Comment: @Trunganhnguyễnthành they all do slightly different things. Reading `:help tabstop` (and softabstop, and shiftwidth, and you probably want shiftround too) is a food start. After that, [this Q](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4244/10604) is ok. And [this is really illustrative](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/)